# rxJava Observer/Observable onSubscribe method optional?

Tags: java, rx-java, observer-pattern

The rxJava specification page for Observable ([http://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html][1]) says: "OnSubscribe (optional)",
but trying to use it I get this error:
class Manager implements Observer

> Class 'Manager' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract
> method 'onSubscribe(Disposable)' in 'Observer'

Seems it is abstract in Observer and thus not optional?
[1]: http://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html

Comment: Optional means you don't have to do anything in the method but you still have to declare the method as the Java language mandates it when implementing interface methods.

Comment: Thanks, I figured something like this - the documentation seems a bit unclear.